# Securing Babaganoush Web Api

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

Loving the Web API and have created some custom ones for our dynamic module. Is there a way we can secure all the web services rather than just the custom ones we have created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When inheriting from `BaseDynamicController<YouCustomModel>`, you can override any of the services like this:

```
    public override IEnumerable<YouCustomModel> Get(int take = 0)
    {
        if (/* Not Authenticated */)
            throw new System.Security.SecurityException("Not authorized to access content");

        return base.Get(take);
    }
```

In a future release, we are looking to allow this to be controlled from a virtual method: https://babaganoush.uservoice.com/forums/259241-general/suggestions/6255143-secured-web-services-option-for-dynamic-content

Comment: Thanks Basem. I assume that the other modules can be overridden the same way so will look into that.

Comment: Yes, but may be a tedious task. What you can do instead is manage permissions for the content themselves in the Sitefinity permissions and enable filtering queries by view permissions: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/knowledge-base/changing-filtering-by-view-permissions-in-5-0